does SNS FIFO topic's message retries to SQS FIFO Queue in strict sequence?
We are working on one pub-sub architecture, where we want to use SNS for fan out to multiple SQS Queues. We have a requirement of strict sequence i.e. events should be in sequence for each clients.
According to SNS, SQS doc we opted for FIFO topic in SNS and FIFO Queue in SQS which guarantee strict order. I also see their is a retry mechanism by SNS in case of SQS failures (server/network issues)
My question is, with SNS's strong retry (over 100k times in 23 days) , will the strict sequence maintained at SQS side?
i.e will the failed messages be delivered first before any new message is delivered? Or will it be delivered in parallel?
I tried replicating SNS retry mechanism using localstack, but for no avail as they have only 3 start support for SQS and SNS(CRUD operation support), not sure if they have same retry implementation
I tried changing SQS policy in aws, but I retry is only triggered on server errors.
So I was not able to test it out.

Once messages have been received by Amazon SQS, they will then be provided to consumers in FIFO order for messages with the same MessageGroupId. Messages with different MessageGroupId values can be delivered in parallel, but in FIFO order. Also, if the consumer is receiving multiple messages in a batch there can be multiple messages with the same MessageGroupId, but no additional messages will be provided until the 'older' messages are processed. So, it depends on how the SNS-SQS combination is setting the MessageGroupId.

@johnRotenstein is FIFO order maintained in case of retries by SNS.?Assuming all messages have same MessageGroupId
